# Center 3 divs to make a slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap and I want to make a slide show of a few images :

I have managed to show the images I need in a modal div using this code :

```
<div id="imgContainer" class="modal hide fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
  <div id="stanga" style="height:100%;">
    <img src="./img/stanga.png" style="padding-top:50%;position:absolute;">
  </div>
  <div id="pozica">
    <img src="./lucrari/BRD1.png">
  </div>
  <div id="dreapta" style="float:right;">
    <img src="./img/dreapta.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

The result I get is something Like this :

[image: bad divs]

How can I achive something like this ? I mean center the main photo and the left right buttons?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use default TB carousel? http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a absolute position on the **prev** and **next** arrows should do the trick

[**here is an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yPQPx/1/)

**CSS:**

```
#stanga img{
margin : 30px;
}

#pozica,#dreapta{
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px
}

#dreapta{
    right: 5px;
}
#pozica{
    left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try a CSS3 animation where you change the background everytime (CSS keyframes). JQuery also has solutions for this to create a slideshow.

Comment: the project has some particularities implementing something from scratch suits me best in this case. juqery slideshow is not as flexible as I want it to be.Thanks for the tip tough

Answer (score 1):

css code :

```
.modal hide fade in{
position:relative;
}
#stanga , #pozica , #dreapta{
position:absolute;
left:50%;
right:50%;
top:50%;
bottom:50%;
}
```

for next and previous buttons yo can use :

```
#nxt{
float:right;
z-index:100
}
#prv{
float:left;
z-index:100
}
```

Comment: didn't work the image is out of the screen an the buttons have the same position. thaks for your answer